# Is it possible to stop browsers or other internet facing programs from accessing my local (system) time?.

Tags: windows, google-chrome, vpn, time

I am using VPN and I don't want my local time info to be accessible. I am using windows 10 and chrome broswer. I can change the local system time but I am looking for another alternative.

Comment: This is done by webdelevopers either using java or flash. You would have to block scripts. This is a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/noscript-suite-lite/ahnanjpbkghcdgmlchbcfoiefnifjeni?hl=en-US) which may help with that.

Comment: Changing your local time would make a fingerprint of your PC even more unique. It is better to maintain your time synchronised with global sources. Instead, change the time-zone setting